# SASS files management in Git version control system in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano, sass

I'm using SASS files in Rails development. And I wonder if I should
`gitignore` generated CSS files.

The problem with adding CSS files in Git is that they are simply redundant.
SASS files at `public/stylesheets/sass` are the files I need.

So I have the following lines in `gitignore`:

```
# public/stylesheets/*.css
```

But if I do this, when I push my app to Heroku, there's no CSS files obviously.

- What could be the best practices for managing SASS/CSS files?

I have never tried assets packing (e.g., minifying CSS files for production environment),
but I plan to do that as well when I deploy to non-Heroku environment with Capistrano.

Comment: I found the following links after researching: http://mdeering.com/posts/021-rails-capistrano-and-rake-tasks-for-sass-with-asset_packager and http://blog.codefront.net/2008/08/07/sass-with-rails-avoiding-disappearing-stylesheets-in-production/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a heroku blog post about their plugin to generate CSS from your Sass on their servers.
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/8/18/heroku_sass/

Comment: You might have forgot the URL to the blog post.

Answer (score 2):

My method is to keep a dedicated local branch to track everything that will be pushed to Heroku. Your mileage may vary, but this works well for me and feels pretty cleanly organized.

Comment: I like this approach, but it's not easy for most folks to pull off. Maybe you can blog about how you did it and post a link here for posterity?

Answer (score 1):

You should not commit the generated CSS files into Git and to deal with read-only filesystems (like Heroku) you should use the [hassle gem](https://github.com/pedro/hassle) (the [sass_on_heroku](https://github.com/heroku/sass_on_heroku) plugin is now deprecated).